# How to merge two mat in opencv android

Tags: android, opencv

I use submat function to cut out part of a picture and did some processing. I now have two mats to use.

```
Mat originalMat = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(originalBmp, originalMat);
Rect rect = new Rect(left, top, right - left, bottom - top);
Mat roi_img = originalMat.submat(rect);
Imgproc.cvtColor(roi_img, roi_img, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2Lab);
#some processing to roi_img....
Imgproc.cvtColor(roi_img, roi_img, Imgproc.COLOR_Lab2BGR);
```

I find the cvtColor function maybe changes the reference of roi_img. The processing is disable for originalMat. originalMat is the same as before.
I want to merge the originalMat and the roi_img.

I try to use copyto and clone function, but it is not worked.

```
        Mat mat = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(originalBmp, mat);
        Rect rect = new Rect(40, 40, 100, 100);
        Mat roi_img = mat.submat(rect);
        double[] value = new double[]{255, 255, 255};
        Imgproc.cvtColor(roi_img, roi_img, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2Lab);
        for (int i = 0; i < roi_img.rows(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < roi_img.cols(); j++) {
                roi_img.put(i, j, value);
            }
        }
        Imgproc.cvtColor(roi_img, roi_img, Imgproc.COLOR_Lab2BGR);

        Mat roi_img2 = mat.submat(rect);
//        roi_img2 = roi_img.clone();
        roi_img.copyTo(roi_img2);
        showMat(mat);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistakes.  I should use `cvtColor` function on the originalMat.